# node.js app symlink relative path resolution

Tags: linux, filesystems, path, symbolic-link, node.js

I have a node.js application that lays under `/opt/myapp`.
There is a folder called "plugins" (`/opt/myapp/plugins`).
In the plugins folder (oh wonder) are stored plugins that are loaded on startup.

I dont want to put the plugins directly there (for development reasons).
How can i link plugins from everywhere to the app plugins folder?

The problem im facing is, when i create a symlink there (`ln -s /var/myapp/plugins/32f44273-3ff8-452c-a087-34c4b4b67e62 /opt/myapp/plugins/`) the path resolution in the plugin does not work anymore and other files could not be loaded because the plugins "think" its not under `/var/myapp/plugins` but `/var/myapp/plugins/32f44273-3ff8-452c-a087-34c4b4b67e62`

What would be the correct way to "simulate" that the plugins folder lays under `/opt/myapp/plugins/` but is in reality somewhere else on the filesystem, with correct relative path resolution?

I want exactly the same functionality as the plugin is stored under `/opt/myapp/plugins` but with a symlink.

EDIT:
Seems like i can do this with "mount":

```sh
mount --bind /var/myapp/plugins/32f44273-3ff8-452c-a087-34c4b4b67e62 /opt/myapp/plugins/32f44273-3ff8-452c-a087-34c4b4b67e62/
```

Found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/372590/1034948

But what i dont like, is that under Ubuntu 18.04 in the taskbar the HDD pops up as mounted. Is there a way to hide it?